# Removing specific set of characters?

Tags: python, character

I know a code like this

```
translated1 = str(''.join( c for c in translated2 if c not in "[']" ))
```

will remove any instances of [ or ' or ] but how would I code it so that it removes "---" exactly this.

I don't want it to remove any instances of "-", only if those 3 are together at once.

How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: `translated2.replace('---', '')`?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily by **regular expression**.
You can read more about python regular expression [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

You can use it like this-

```
import re
str1 = 'there is three --- and now single - and now two --'
str2 = re.sub('---', '', str1)
print(str2)
```

Output-

```
there is three  and now single - and now two --
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/repls/ClosedDrabFlash)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace(patt, repl)`:

```
s = "---test--test-test----"
print(s.replace("---", ""))
# "test--test-test-"
```

You could also do it using `re` if you want something more extensible.